# How to configure stencil so that generated ts file doesnt come with double quotes

Tags: html, css, typescript, stenciljs

Right now whenever I ran command `stencil build --docs`, it will generate `components.d.ts` with below content

```js
/* eslint-disable */
/* tslint:disable */
/**
 * This is an autogenerated file created by the Stencil compiler.
 * It contains typing information for all components that exist in this project.
 */
import { HTMLStencilElement, JSXBase } from "@stencil/core/internal";
export namespace Components {
    interface MyButton {
        /**
          * Button text
         */
        "text": string;
    }
    interface MyTab {
        /**
          * Tab active
         */
        "active": boolean;
```

If you noticed, all properties are actually with double quotes, I am wondering what can I do to remove the quotes, because we know that for a `ts` file these quotes aren't necessarily.

And below is my `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "h"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that prop names can contain dashes and thus all prop names are just quoted for simplicity, when generating the file.

Stencil provides no configuration for this but it is also totally unnecessary to change that because 1) the file is auto-generated (so there's no point in formatting it differently) and 2) it's a declaration file that does not contain any runtime code (i. e. file size does not matter). TypeScript editors like VS Code provide good intellisense so you'll probably never have to interact with this file anyway, it'll just give you good auto-completion and inline docs.

You can usually git-ignore the file quite safely (with some increased build time on first build because it needs to be regenerated), even though the official recommendation is to add it into source-control.